# What's the subject of this relative clause?

Tags: subordonnées, antécédent

I'm reading *Rousseau, citoyen du futur*, by Jean-Paul Jouary, and somewhat embarrassingly, I can't figure out this sentence:

> La seconde partie complète ce corpus, proposant des textes qui éclairent et précisent l'exposé précédent (textes de Rousseau mais aussi d'autres auteurs, **qu'il critique ou accompagne**)...

What does that “**il**” refer to? Rousseau himself? The corpus?

Comment: Are you sure of your text? "or" seems weird here. Can you confirm you put the exact text?

Comment: Yep, that's the exact text. You can see it on Amazon's preview feature. (It's in the Introduction--I'm not sure how to link directly to it though.)

Comment: cl-r: are you sure about your edit ? (that was the point of my interrogation)

Comment: @AnneAunyme -- *or* ( *Conjonction de coordination*, vers le milieu de https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/or#Fran.C3.A7ais ) ne peut coordonner deux verbes, mais, *ou* donne le choix de l'un *ou* l'autre. Alan a glissé le mot anglais dans une phrase en français :). Si vous faites une recherche de la phrase citée, vous trouverez au 4ème § le mot *ou*. -- N.B. l'URL de recherche est composée de 703 caractères... elle ne passent pas dans un commentaire !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"il" is referring to **Rousseau**, because it's him who's *criticizing and sharing* the other texts.

Comment: Ah, got it, that makes perfect sense. Merci !

Comment: @AlanO'Donnell -- C'est J.J. Rousseau qui critique ou accompagne...  mais cela se passe dans *l'exposé précédent* : votre question est très pertinente. De toutes façons les  parenthèses enclosent "la lettre" du texte, et il faut donc s'y tenir, mais pas son "esprit" : il y a très souvent plusieurs lectures pour une phrase, cela vient de l'écriture où celui ou celle qui écrit a un choix limité pour articuler sa pensée, mais peut aussi éclairer simultanément *la lettre et l'esprit* d'un texte.